# How to work with existing database in Laravel 5.7

Tags: laravel

How can I use my existing database in Laravel 5.7? Please guide me to proceed with my existing database to develop in Laravel framework. I have to use my database without losing those data in Laravel framework.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Please take a look at [how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Did you do any research? you can simply connect an existing database and use the [`DB`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/database) class to use it. i put this as a comment because it does not really provide a solution just some pointers in where to look.

Comment: If you don't need an eloquent, just point your config to the DB and start using DB class.

Comment: I have tried googling but I couldn't find any solution for using existing database with laravel framewok. Please prodive some guidance regarding this

Answer (score 2):

Just link to it in `.env` and off you go! If you wanna use Eloquent and your DB doesn't adhere to Laravel defaults you can configure things like table names and primary keys as described [here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent)